# Any ways to use GitHub's client with BitBucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

It was possible to do this before but when GitHub updated their client it seems this feature went missing. Anyone has a workaround or now how to do it?

Reason for question: I really love GitHubs client for its ease and much rather use it instead of SourceTree. (I use BitBucket because we mainly go with private repos).

Comment: What is missing in the recent GitHub client update?